# How to connect to Office Online Server in Office365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-365

I just wondering if we can use existing Office Online Server in Office365 for SP2013 on premise. If yes, how this can be achieve?

In SP2013 we normally run `Get-SPWOPIBinding` to find out the server binding and to connect to Office web App we normally run 
`New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName`. Is this the same command if I want to connect to the existing new Office Online Server in Office365?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. There is no official documentation about that. I suppose it's not here to be connected to SharePoint OnPremises.

I did some research:

Pressed F12 in SharePoint Online to get the URL of OfficeOnline-Server in O365. Then tried to communicate directly via Browser with "/hosting/discovery": Got a useful response
[image: OOS-Response]

Connected this OOS to my SP2013 OnPremises Environment
[image: New-SPWopiBinding]

Finally i tried to use OOS in my DocumentLibrary. It doesn't work because OOS in O365 cannot download the document from my OnPremises library. Screen stays grey.
[image]

I am not able to test the result if SharePoint OnPrem is available via Internet. Might work. But i am very sure it's not intended by MS to be consumed via OnPremises. So it could break at any time.

Installing a local OOS-Server is neither time nor resource intensive. You should consider that!

Comment: public URL's seems to be:  https://broadcast.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery or like: https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible as you cannot make a trusted connection to the Office 365 version of Office Online Server. Instead you need to deploy Office Online Server on-prem. But remember that you must maintain Office 2016 User CALs for each user consuming OOS (these can either be VL or O365 subscription versions).